# Independent slices of 2-swap permutations

Tags: algorithm, permutation

Given an algorithm of 2-swap permutation enumeration like Steinhaus–Johnson–Trotter algorithm (but not necessarily of adjacent items), I would like to find a way to do the following:

1. [the basics] A function that, from the starting vector [1,2,3..N] efficiently go along all permutations (iteratively and/or recursively) swapping 2 elements from the previous one.
2. A function that, given an index of some permutation [1,N!], can easily calculate it (I mean, find it without needing to go along the preceding ones) and then keep going from there.
3. The opposite, find the index of a given permutation compared to an also given starting one.

In other words, the functions to slice a list of 2-swap permutations into arbitrary sized independent blocks.

Pseudocode and/or C-like code are very welcome.

Links to articles/books too.

Ref.: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutations_by_swapping

Answer (score 0):

I've posted Java code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877504/johnson-trotter-algorithm/28241384?s=1|0.0000#28241384) for the Johnson-Trotter algorithm (with Even's speedup) implemented iteratively rather than recursively.

I think this may help you with your questions 1, and possibly also 2 and 3.