# Johnson-Trotter Permutation

Tags: permutation

I am trying to write a program that can generate permutations using the Johnson-Trotter method with varying number of elements. I am still confused on how to get the permutations exactly. For 5 elements, I can only get this far and then I get stuck. I am not asking for all of them just a few more so I can get the pattern down.

1 2 3 4 5

1 2 3 5 4

1 2 5 3 4

1 5 2 3 4

5 1 2 3 4

Answer (score 0):

I found the following page:

http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/JohnsonTrotter.java.html

Try running this Java program step by step, it will surely be of great help...

Answer (score 0):

I have used the Johnson-Trotter algorithm in a card-melding game. The princeton.edu link mentioned above is widely quoted, but pretty confusing. And the code I've seen is either recursive (yuck) or inefficient. I rewrote it as an iterator, and it works great in my game. See my other post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28241384/4266886 with (very short) code. Let me know if I can help further.